# PowerScript - Can anybody get me the output of this code or explain me ? I need this for migration

Tags: powerbuilder

string(lds_data.getitemstring(i, "column1"), "@@@@@@;@@@@@@")

string(lds_data.getitemstring(i, "column2"), "000;-00;'000';'000'")

string(lds_data.getitemnumber(i, "column3"), "0;0;' ';' '")

Comment: Please give me some examples with values and output. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string constructor has two syntaxes, the one you are using being the one allowing you to provide the format of the string you are creating, via a mask.
You can find information and exemples at the following address (which is appeon's documentation for strings). You are interested in syntax 1.

https://www.appeon.com/support/documents/appeon_online_help/pb2019/powerscript_reference/ch10s691.html#xREF_13876_Syntax_1